# Python dictionary comparison

Tags: python

Problem:
I am trying to implement distance vector routing protocol and I need to track distances of Nodes/Routers (A, B, C) and distances from their neighbors (1,2,3) and update the best path (source router to destination router) if one of the router learns about another best path from its neighbors by processing and sending updated distance vectors. More details here en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol

I am trying to compare two dictionaries (`a` & `b`) and if I find any of the keys of `b` (i.e. `'B'`) present in `a` then I want to add the value of `'B'` (i.e. `1`) from `a` in to `'C'` (i.e. `2`) from `b` so the output looks similar to following:

```
a = {'A': {'B': 1}}

b = {'B': {'C': 2}}
```

Final Output:

```
a = {'A': {'B': 1, 'C': 3}}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid dictionary ... There is no key associated with `{'C': 3}`.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed final output format.

Comment: I'm still confused... Why is it `{'C': 3}` rather than `{'C': 2}`?  Why is the whole thing nested in the key `'A'`?

Comment: @mgilson, because 2 + 1 is three, i.e `a["A]["B"]  +  b["B"]["C"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with dictionaries, but with sets it is. For example,

```
s = {'K':'L', 'L':'K', 'Q':'P'}
p = {'K':'L', 'Q':'P'}

# for python 3
k = s.values() & p.values() # k is now {'L', 'P'}
# for python 2
k = s.viewvalues() & p.viewvalues() # is now {'L', 'P'}
```

Look at set documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: It is possible with dictionaries.

Comment: I need this kind of data structure as I am trying to implement distance vector  routing protocol and I need to track distances of Nodes/Routers like A, B, C etc and their distances from their neighbors 1,2,3 etc and update the best paths (router and distance) if one of the router learns about another best path from its neighbors by sending and receiving distance vectors. More details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol.

Comment: @Corgs, My problem is little complex as I am dealing with nested dictionaries and output varies based on the keys and their values.